# How to split files?

Tags: perl

`Input.txt`:

```
line.....1
line.....2
line.....3
.....

line.....3
line.....4
line.....5
.....

line.....4
line.....5
line.....6
.....

line.....5
line.....6
line.....7
.....
```

Condition for output file names mentioned in `name.txt`.

`name.txt`:

```
chapter01.txt
chapter02.txt
chapter03.txt
chapter04.txt
```

#### need output for following `txt` files

`chapter01.txt`:

```
line.....1
line.....2
line.....3
.....
```

`chapter02.txt`:

```
line.....3
line.....4
line.....5
.....
```

`chapter03.txt`:

```
line.....4
line.....5
line.....6
.....
```

`chapter04.txt`:

```
line.....5
line.....6
line.....7
.....
```

Comment: What determines where to split the files? On an empty line?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -vRS= '{RS="\n";getline f < "name.txt";RS=""
            print > f; close(f)}' < input.txt
```